# interface between c++ and blue print in unreal engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a character which need some custom AI logic and I will comfortable to write in c++ code. I have blue print for the object for other purpose. How do I combine c++ code with blue print ? Can I do that at all ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with unreal engine, but would this be of any help? [link](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Gameplay/ClassCreation/CodeAndBlueprints/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your logic into C++ class derived from Actor and mark some methods with UFUNCTION() macro [UE Docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Functions/index.html). Then you can call native methods from BP.

Answer (score 0):

You can write common logic in backend, but all methods what you need to use within UE4 toolset you can connect with mentioned above UFUNCTION() macro.